# I Cannot update using stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I got a serious error and this error is strange. It says Error updating record: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. It happened when I added this: `$sql="Call getMedicine('$id')";`.

here's my code:

```
<?php
require("db.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql="Call getMedicine('$id')"; //strange error 
//Error updating record: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$test = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
        {
            die("Error: Data not found..");
        }
        $product_name=$test['product_name'];
        $description= $test['description'];                 
        $date=$test['date'];
        $quantity=$test['quantity'];
        $price=$test['price'];

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $product_name_save=$_POST['product_name_txt'];
    $description_save=$_POST['description_txt'];
    $date_save=$_POST['date_txt'];
    $quantity_save=$_POST['quantity_txt'];
    $price_save=$_POST['price_txt'];

    $sql="Call editMedicine('$id', '$product_name_save', '$description_save', '$date_save', '$quantity_save', '$price_save')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }    

    header("Location: view_medicine.php");      
}
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a new query while you're still not done using the results of an old one.

You should call `mysqli_free_result($result);` at some point before calling the `editMedicine` stored procedure.

Comment: please give me an example because I have no idea on how to use that.

Comment: Right after the line that says `$test = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` add another one: `mysqli_free_result($result);`